# How to add a variable value inside a text variable in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In my C++ code, I am executing some commands using python as follows:

```
std::string word = "Something";
std::cout << word;                         //will execute using C++
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");          // will execute using Python
```

The problem is how to pass `word` to Python ?

I want something like this: `PyRun_SimpleString("Hello %" %word);`

In Python you can do: `"Hello {}".format(word)` and the result `"Hello Something"`

I found something like this: `sprintf(str, "hello %s", word);`
But the problem is `printf` or `sprintf` will send it to console and will not return the value of word.

Comment: `sprintf` will _not_ send it to the console.

Comment: Thank you. so can I use it in my example like this: `new_word = sprintf(str, "Hello %s", word);` ?

Comment: `sprintf()` returns the number of characters copied into `str`. You would need `new_word = str;` after `sprintf()` exits.  But you really shouldn't be using `sprintf()` anyway.  That is the C way of formatting strings. The C++ way is to use `std::string::operator+` or a `std::ostringstream` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you use the `+` operator to concatenate `std::string` objects.

`PyRun_SimpleString()` takes a `const char*` as input.  `std::string` has a `c_str()` method for obtaining a `const char*` for the string.

So, you can do this:

```
std::string s = "Hello " + word;
PyRun_SimpleString(s.c_str());
```

Or simply this:

```
PyRun_SimpleString(("Hello " + word).c_str());
```

Alternatively, you can use a `std::ostringstream` instead to build up a formatted string:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Hello " << word;
PyRun_SimpleString(oss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is really helpful.

Comment: Sidenote: There's no `operator+` for numerical values (int, unsigned long, float, double, ...), only for character, C-strings and `std::string`. So if you need the former, you'd be using the `std::ostringstream` variant...